# How to show a view controller using a navigation controller segue, including back segue (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I have to view controller, One has a button and the other is embed in a navigation controller. I Don't know how to make a proper segue to that second view controller including a back (unwind) segue. That is in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to use a navigation controller. Go and select your view in the storyboard, and select Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller. Do the same for the second view. Now, add a button in the first view that connect to the second view on a click. Make sure when you drag and drop that it's a push segue.

[image]
 Voila! You should now have your navigation controller working.

Comment: But that does not include an unwind (back) segue

Comment: It automatically adds it to the top of the iPhone screen. The user will see a back button, and upon pressing it, it'll take the user back to the button view. You can programmatically call the unwind segue as well, would you like that code?

Comment: Sigh... there is no code. Just add the design you see above and run the application.